# Ionic 4 beta 18 - ion-item and ion-button with routerLink don't change route

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7, beta, ionic4

I just updated from ionic 4 beta 17 to 18 and a breaking change in `<ion-item>` and `<ion-button>` was introduced. The **href** was replaced with **routerLink**.

I added this to my code and now the routing doesn't work anymore.
Most of the time the compiler throws errors and says, that routerLink does not exist in ion-item.

What did i do wrong? Or is it angular?

```
"@ionic/angular": "~4.0.0-beta.18",
"@ionic/core": "~4.0.0-beta.18",
"@angular/core": "^7.1.3",
"@angular/router": "~7.1.3",

<ion-item text-wrap class="nav-item" routerDirection="forward" 
        [routerLink]="p.url"
        *ngFor="let p of listOfPages; let i = index"
        [class.active-item]="checkActivePath(p.url)"
        [class.last-item]="i === (listOfPages.length - 1)">
    <ion-label class="nav-label">
        <ion-img [src]="p.icon" class="nav-icon"></ion-img>
        <div class="text-block">
            {{ p.title }}
        </div>
    </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is what finally worked for me:

1. Make sure to include the **RouterModule** in every module.
2. In every nested module I used

   ```
   const routes: Routes = [{
       path: '',
       component: AboutUsPage
   }];
   ```
3. I imported `RouterModule.forChild(routes)` there aswell.
4. For routes I added `/` before the path. Like `'/home'`
5. In **app-routing.ts** I used `{path: 'about-us/:id', component: AboutUsPage},`.

Answer (score 6):

Import `RouterModule` in the module file of the module where the template is (the module where routerLink is used):

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...
        RouterModule,
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you. That gave me some needed insights.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the missing " after routerDirection?

```
routerDirection="forward
```

EDIT: when you are using a Ionic component, you should use href. RouterLink is for non-Ionic components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot the quotation mark but that wasn't the problem. 
In the changelog for beta 18 the team states, that they changed to `[routerLink]` for consistency reasons.